# How can I make the text input be sent to another page?

Tags: php, html, css, post, get

I'm running this locally, the page that features this code has this address:

> search.php?page=content

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
$id=$_GET['page']; if ($id=='content') echo "  
  <div id='content'> 
    <form action='search.php?page=generated' method='POST' name='value'>
                <input type='text'>
                <input type='submit' value='Send'>
            </form>
  </div>";} else echo ""; 
?>
```

I want the text inputted in this form to be sent to

> search.php?page=generated

I thought the right way to do this was:

```
@$temp=$_POST['value'];
echo $temp;
```

But nothing ever gets sent to 'value'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to change the `<input type='text'>` to have the name rather than the `<form>` tag.

Comment: Oh my god... I feel so dumb right now. Thank you.